# How to enable the past dates of jQuery inline datePicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using inline calendar of this jQuery inline datePicker plugin.
By default the days before the current date was disabled. 
I want to enable them.
Do you have any idea?
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/inlineDatePicker.html

```
$(function () {
    $('.turn-me-into-datepicker').datePicker({inline:true})
            .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function (e, selectedDate, $td) {
                console.log('You selected ' + selectedDate);
            }
    );
});
```

Under Html:
I've used the class name inside a div.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean [**this**](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/inlineDatePicker.html) plugin?  You can check their [**documentation**](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html) for startDate option.

Comment: $(function()
{
 $('.turn-me-into-datepicker')
  .datePicker({inline:true})
  .bind(
   'dateSelected',
   function(e, selectedDate, $td)
   {
    console.log('You selected ' + selectedDate);
   }
  );
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check out their [documentation](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html) for the appropriate option or other [live examples](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/) from their website.

Going back to the topic, using their demo example:

```
$('#inline-3')
    .datePicker(
        {
            inline:true,
            startDate:'01/01/2000' // first selectable date is 1st Jan 2000
        }
    );
```

Comment: @saran: If you got it then accept an answer. Do the same for all your answered questions. It helps users who will try to help you in the future as well as future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the minDate option is null.